# How to detect only contours that are within another contour in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have the image shown below. How could I detect only the contours of the 4 squares that are inside? I have tried doing it, but I only managed to detect the squares that have contours within them, but I need to know it the other way around.

[image]

Comment: please edit what you have tried so far in your pots (code)

Comment: findContours with hierarchy, filter by depth (requires a predicate function that walks up the hierarchy and counts levels; memoization trivial), done. -- and maybe think about inverting the picture in the first place. fC() finds white components on black background. you seem to consider the squares and the wide black border to be object, and white to be background. -- @TomBlums I hope you'll give it a try and post an answer yourself. doing that is perfectly fine.

Comment: Another approach might be to flood fill the border with white. Then invert and get the external contours for the boxes.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it this way: I found hierarchy of all contours and then found 4 contours with the same hierarchy number. Those 4 contours are the 4 squares in the picture.

```
for cnt in zip(contours, hierarchy):
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt[0], 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(cnt[0], True), True)
if len(approx) == 4:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt[0])
    ratio = float(w) / h
    #print(cnt[1])
    if 0.9 <= ratio <= 1.1:
        correct_contours.append(cnt[1].tolist())

hierarchy_values = []
for array in correct_contours:
    hierarchy_values.append(array[3])
value_counts = Counter(hierarchy_values)
values_occuring_exactly_four_times = [value for value, count in value_counts.items() if count == 4 and value != 0]

for cnt in zip(contours, hierarchy):
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt[0], 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(cnt[0], True), True)
    if len(approx) == 4:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt[0])
        ratio = float(w) / h
        #print(cnt[1])
        if 0.9 <= ratio <= 1.1:
            if cnt[1][3] == values_occuring_exactly_four_times[0]:
                cv2.putText(frame, 'Correct', (x, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (36, 255, 12), 2)
                Moments = cv2.moments(cnt[0])
                xCenter = int(Moments["m10"] / Moments["m00"])
                yCenter = int(Moments["m01"] / Moments["m00"])
                yValues.append(yCenter)
                xValues.append(xCenter)
                detected_squares.append(approx)



cv2.drawContours(frame, detected_squares, -1, (0,255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow('image with drawn contours', frame)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```